# Nuxt.js Static Site Generation Third Plugin CSS

Tags: nuxt.js

I have been trying and failing to pull in third party plugin CSS into my Nuxt.js site setup as SSG. My plan was to create a number of Vue components and publish them, import them as plugins into Nuxt, this would allow me to re-use these components on multiple Nuxt.js sites in the future.

Currently I have created a external Vue component using rollup and can successfully import it into Nuxt.js.

My plugin code looks like:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Features from 'features'
import 'features/dist/styles.css'

Vue.use(Features)
```

If I run `npm run dev` in SSR mode it renders the component and the CSS correctly, however if I run `npm run generate` & then `npm run start`, it loads the component and content but does not include the CSS.

I must note I am currently using yarn to symlink the external component so I can test before publishing, so I did enable `followSymlinks` in the nuxt.config.js but had no success.

The CSS being imported is tailwind however that is processed via the rollup before I am import it so its recieved as just standard CSS in Nuxt.js.

Any help would be greatly appeciated.

Update:

As requested here is a link to a repo of the third party component in question. https://github.com/wizzer711/sfc-vue-component

My nuxt.config.js looks like:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import reject from 'lodash/reject'

export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'test-frontend',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    { src: '@/plugins/features.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/inject.js' }
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxt/typescript-build'
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    // '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
    '@nuxtjs/strapi'
  ],
  strapi: {
    entities: ['pages', 'categories', 'navigations'],
    url: process.env.API_URL
  },
  i18n: {
    strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
    locales: ['en', 'en-US', 'eu'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    seo: true
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    followSymlinks: true
  },

  generate: {

    routes () {
      const pageRoutes = axios.get(`${process.env.API_URL}/pages?_locale=all`).then((res) => {
        const filteredData = reject(res.data, { slug: 'homepage' })
        return filteredData.map((page) => {
          const routeUrl = (page.locale !== 'en') ? `/${page.locale}/${page.slug}` : `/${page.slug}`
          return {
            route: routeUrl,
            payload: page
          }
        })
      })

      const blogRoutes = axios.get(`${process.env.API_URL}/blogs`).then((res) => {
        return res.data.map((page) => {
          return {
            route: `/blog/${page.slug}`,
            payload: page
          }
        })
      })

      return Promise.all([pageRoutes, blogRoutes]).then((values) => {
        return [...values[0], ...values[1]]
      })
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: There is a decent amount of configuration here. Not a plugin expert but I think that it could be nice to have a [repro] with your current setup, to allow people to help you debug faster!

Comment: Thx for the suggestion @kissu, I have updated my original post with a link to a basic vue component repo which when imported into the Nuxt app causes the issues mentioned. I have also added snippets to as much Nuxt code as possible. Its a little tricky to share everything as I am using strapi CMS to generate routes also.